# Best Framework For Accessing OpenLDAP With Seam & JBoss AS?

Tags: java, seam, openldap

We are currently implementing a portal to our web based services. The portal and services are written with Seam and we are using OpenLDAP to store the security data such as users, groups and permissions. So far we have looked at writing our own code to access LDAP but are there any existing APIs that we could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're a Spring user, I'd look into the [Spring LDAP modules](http://www.springsource.org/ldap).  They're beautifully done; they follow the idiom laid down by their JDBC implementation.  Very clean, very nice.

Answer (score 0):

We did this for our web application a while ago and investigated the following:
http://developers.sun.com/sw/docs/examples/appserver/ldap.html

However, we ended up just using the LDAP support built in to Tomcat, since basic authentication was enough for us.

Here is an example on how we set up out authentication in tomcat:
http://blog.mc-thias.org/?c=1&more=1&pb=1&tb=1&title=tomcat_ldap_authentication

Answer (score 0):

[JLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/jldap/overview.html)

> The LDAP Class Libraries for Java (JLDAP) allow you to write applications to access, manage, update, and search for information stored in directories accessible using LDAPv3.